# Pinterest API to to pin pictures of image on iphone code sample

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pinterest

Hi Any of you had been able to access to pinterest api to post pictures or images on either iphone or ipad? if you can can you post some sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no API available, but you apparently can sign up to get notified [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?pli=1&formkey=dHBvVkVsN2NzUVEybDhjeFZ0ZzFKWnc6MQ#gid=0) when it becomes available.